# "TypeError: <class> is not a constructor" after exporting it in index.js at npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I created the npm package [tcx-file-class](https://github.com/stratis-vip/tcx-file-class) which handles tcx files the way I want to analyse the data afterwards. So it creates (among others) an Activity class.

Activity class exported from the package in the index.ts file in this way:

```
import TcxFile from "./dist/classes/tcxFile"
import Activity from "./dist/classes/activity"
//other imports here

export { TcxFile, Activity,
       //other classes 
       }
```

So when I try to import the class from the package index file like this:

```
import {Activity} from 'tcx-file-class'

const a = new Activity();
```

I get the following error:

```
const a = new tcx_file_class_1.Activity();
      ^

TypeError: tcx_file_class_1.Activity is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stratis/Desktop/development/production/ts/events/dist/index.js:11:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
```

but when I import the class from the package class file, like this:

```
import {Activity} from '../node_modules/tcx-file-class/dist/classes/activity'

const a = new Activity();
```

everything work's just fine.

So, I guess that the exporting procedure is the problem but I can't spot the error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In the code on the top, you're importing `Activity` as the *default export* from `activity`, while in the code on the bottom, you're importing `Activity` as a *named export* from `activity`. I guess it's a named export, not a default export. Change top to `import { Activity } from "./dist/classes/activity"`

Comment: @CertainPerformance i do this because activity.ts file which declare the Activity class has only this class, so it is the default export.

Comment: does your Activity class export it as default or as named import?

Comment: *activity.ts file which declare the Activity class has only this class, so it is the default export* - no, it doesn't, https://github.com/stratis-vip/tcx-file-class/blob/master/dist/classes/activity.d.ts , there are several exports. Even then, named exports are easier to handle because you can do `export * from './activity'` in index.ts. Default exports are well-suited for end points (index), not for internal modules.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my bad!!!

Comment: @estus my badd!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me (and as  CertainPerformance pointed out in the comments) that You are exporting Activity as a named export like

`export { Activity }` and not `export default Activity`

You will need to change your index.ts file's imports to

```
import {TcxFile} from "./dist/classes/tcxFile"
import {Activity} from "./dist/classes/activity"
```

to be able to use named imports.

Comment: I get `unexpected token export`